# Implementing my own generic collection in C#

Tags: c#, generic-collections

I am trying to write my own generic collection (`List<T>`) in C# but got confused with the interfaces. As I understand, in order to create my own collection, I need to implement several interfaces, like ICollection, IList, IEnumerator, IEnumerable etc. But I can't really understand which ones I need.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with the collection. Adding items? Removing items? Searching? Index-based access? Ordering? ... But chances are high you don´t need your own collection-type, as the existing ones should be enough. Or is this just an exercise?

Comment: "But I can't really understand which ones I need." which interfaces are you going to use?

Comment: I wouldn't use `List<T>`, either, as this could easily be confused with the version already in .Net

Comment: You only need to implement IList<T>... if you do that, you will have already done ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, and IEnumerable.

Comment: This is my homework, to create my own generic collection)

Comment: Actually you don´t need to impelement **any** interface. So what exactly do you want to do with your collection?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I need all the things you have listed

Comment: What about iterating the items? You should provide far more information **into your question**, not into the comments.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44824519/c-sharp-ienumerable-icollection-ilist-or-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement `IList<T>` for access to the collection's items by their index. `IList<T>` inherits from `ICollection<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable`, so you get those anyway.

For a more basic collection without access to an item by index, you implement `ICollection<T>`, which comes with `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable` through inheritance.

You *can* additionally implement `IReadOnlyList<T>` (or `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` respectively), but that is usually not necessary.

You should also look into inheriting from `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>`  instead, which is the recommended way, because the usual boilerplate interface implementations are already done for you and you can concentrate on the parts that make your collection special.

Comment: Depending on what OP wants to do with the colelection, implementing `IList` could or could not be neccessary.

Comment: I clarified the issue of lists versus collections.

Comment: Ok, I got it, that makes sense now

Comment: I will mark it as an answer in 4 minutes as Stackoverflow doesn't let me do this now)

Answer (score 0):

What is your collection for? If you implement `IEnumerable<T>` (which entails implementing `IEnumerable`, then you've an enumerable object. If you've also got an `Add()` method then you've got an enumerable object that works with collection initialisation. Beyond that, look at the common collection interfaces and ask if they are useful to your use cases, particularly `ICollection<T>` (adding and removal in particular) and `IList<T>` (indexing in particular).