# Web API filters not catching exceptions thrown from a method group

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api, exception, asp.net-web-api-filters

I'm using `WebApi`. I have a custom `ActionFilter` on my base controller and a custom `ExceptionFilter` added globally. Both are inherited from the associated FilterAttributes in the `System.Web.Http.Filters` namespace, not the mvc versions.

I've been getting an exception thrown from a private method within one of my services, this method is what resharper calls a method group, when it's used within a Linq statement (in this case a `select`).

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> GetFoos()
{
    IEnumerable<Bar> bars = _work.BarRepository.GetAll();

    //throw new Exception("I'm visible to the filters");

    IEnumerable<Foo> foos = bars.Select(MakeFooFromBar);

    return foos;
}

private Foo MakeFooFromBar(Bar bar)
{
    // an exception is being thrown here
    // which is not being caught by the filers
    throw new Exception("I am invisible to the filters");
}
```

This exception is not being caught by either filter (see filters below). My action filter says there was no exception and my exception filter is never hit. If I throw an exception prior to the Linq select (the one I've commented out), then the exception is caught as expected.

Using fiddler, what I end up with is this:

```
{  
   "message":"An error has occurred.",
   "exceptionMessage":"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.",
   "exceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException",
   "stackTrace":null,
   "innerException":{  
      "message":"An error has occurred.",
      "exceptionMessage":"I am invisible to the filters",
      "exceptionType":"System.Exception",
      "stackTrace":""
   }
}
```

A portion of my action filter:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    Exception exception = actionExecutedContext.Exception;

    if (exception == null)
    {
        // do things
    }
    else
    {
        // do some other things
    }
}
```

and a portion of my exception filter:

```
public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    // return early on certain kinds of exceptions...

    _loggedErrorService.Log(actionExecutedContext.Exception);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling)

> You can customize how Web API handles exceptions by writing an exception filter. An exception filter is executed when a **controller method** throws any unhandled exception[...]

The problem is that if you return an `IEnumerable<T>` from your WebAPI method, the error will occur during serialization, when the `IEnumerable<T>` is iterated. This is the standard behavior of `Select` (and most other query operators) it only call the method passed to it upon iteration (`MakeFooFromBar` in this case), so the exception will not be thrown when you invoke `Select` but much later.

You could add a `.ToList` to cause the exception to occur inside your method.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about this behavior. Would it be standard practice to return an IList rather than an IEnumerable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228708/what-should-i-use-an-ienumerable-or-ilist

Comment: @JackPettinger I wouldn't necessarily change the return type, the caller is only expected to iterate the result, not use any other methods. The only thing I would change is the kind of `IEnumerable`, that is an `IEnumerable` that is backed up by an in-memory collection rather then a LINQ query which still need to execute non-trivial code to get the result.