# method that yield returns not called from constructor?

Tags: c#

I am having trouble understanding some syntax and inner workings of C#. I have a class with a read-only property Bars set in the constructor.

If I do that using the `InitializeWithYield` method that `yield returns` something, the method is not called fom the constructor. It is instead called every time(!) the property is called. Not what I expected.

If I do it it using a 'plain' method, it works as I expected: initialize the property once and be done.

Clearly, I am not fully understanding the use of `yield`. My question is: why is the `InitializeWithYield` method not called from the constructor, but every time the property is called?

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo(int length)
    {
        // toggle these to see the issue
        Bars = InitializeWithYield(length);
        //Bars = InitializeCalledFromConstructor(length);
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        IBar firstBar = Bars.FirstOrDefault(); // calls InitializeWithYield if in constructor 
        IList<IBar> listOfBar = Bars.ToList(); // calls InitializeWithYield if in constructor
        Console.Write($"First Bar has value {b.Value}");
    }

    IEnumerable<IBar> Bars { get; }

    // shorter syntax, but gets called every time the Bars property is used
    // also, not called from constructor
    IEnumerable<IBar> InitializeWithYield(int number)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            yield return new Bar(i);
        }
    }

    // this only gets called from the constructor, which is what I want
    IEnumerable<IBar> InitializeCalledFromConstructor(int number)
    {
        IList<IBar> result = new List<IBar>();
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            result.Add(new Bar(i));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Call `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` on `InitializeWithYield(length)` to actually fetch those items returned by the iterator method - they are not executed until you actually iterate over them (which ToList/ToArray do). I suggest stepping through it with a debugger or print output to understand how the methods are run. Maybe a better approach here would be to not offer a `Bars` property, and use `InitializeWithYield` method instead everywhere, renamed to `Bars`, with "_length" being a class member, but I don't know the actual meaning of this example class.

Comment: Thank you. I can see *how* your suggestion of adding `.ToList()` solves my issue, but to be honest I do not fully understand it. Why doesn't `InitializeWithYield` 'simply' run? I probably should look more deeply into 'iterator method'.

Comment: A good example of using iterator functions is filtering lists with custom logic. The caller can iterate over the collection which is returned element-by-element by the iterator function until he found the item he needs and then abort the iteration, _before_ the whole collection is iterated. Then, there is no need to reserve memory for the whole list which may have been returned. In fact, `System.Linq` methods work exactly like that.

Comment: That is in fact exactly what I am doing in my real-world application, except that I caught off-guard initializing the collection to work with.

Comment: You do need to keep the base collection you want to filter stored anywhere. That is typically in a property of type `ICollection` or `IList`. `IEnumerable` is _not_ a stored collection. It is only something that _can_ be enumerated _upon request_. I think if you make that intent clear by changing the property to `IList<IBar> Bars`, you'll also see that you can't just assign it the "result" of the iterator method, as that is just an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Ray thank you. An interesting insight. I try to avoid Ilist and ICollection if I can (They are very useful, but why not store something in an IEnumerable if all you want is some gereric 'list' of something. The rationale behind that being if I do not need the overhead, why use it? That may be silly (or not). I am not a veteran C# programmer, it just seems to make sense to me. I might be wrong.

Comment: Using the least specific interface to combat breaking changes is correct, but it's also a question of what is expected from the class (s. all answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228708/what-should-i-use-an-ienumerable-or-ilist). For your sample, it looks like a generator of `Bar` objects. I'd personally put the `InitializeWithYield` code directly into the getter of `Bars`, and only store the `length` given in the constructor as a class readonly member to access it in there (as it seems to constantly limit the number of `Bar` creatable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerators behave quite differently than normal arrays, as evidenced by your code. Their values are lazily loaded or loaded on demand. This is different than a normal array where all values are loaded at once.

So then `InitializeWithYield()` gets called for each uninitialized value.

[What is the yield keyword used for in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476/what-is-the-yield-keyword-used-for-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

It's deferred execution with lazy evaluation. Please see [Deferred Execution Example (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/deferred-execution-example).

[Deferred Execution and Lazy Evaluation in LINQ to XML (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/deferred-execution-and-lazy-evaluation-in-linq-to-xml) is a great article explaining *Deferred Execution* and *Eager vs. Lazy Evaluation*.

I encourage you to read the whole short article, but here are two quotes from it.

Here's one about *Deferred execution*:

> Deferred execution means that the evaluation of an expression is delayed until its *realized* value is actually required.

Here's one about *Eager vs. Lazy Evaluation*:

> - In lazy evaluation, a single element of the source collection is processed during each call to the iterator. This is the typical way in which iterators are implemented.
> - In eager evaluation, the first call to the iterator will result in the entire collection being processed. A temporary copy of the source collection might also be required. For example, the OrderBy method has to sort the entire collection before it returns the first element.

---

Here is another example to display laziness of `IEnumerable`.

```
    public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetNow()
    {
        while (true) { yield return DateTime.Now; }
    }


    public static async Task Main()
    {
        foreach(var now in GetNow())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(now);
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }
    }
```

This will fetch the current time one by one, each second.

```
20/10/2019 08:00:45
20/10/2019 08:00:46
20/10/2019 08:00:47
20/10/2019 08:00:48
20/10/2019 08:00:49
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick/short answer, but I would recommend reading more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield

The yield/return statement in c# results into a state machine being built in the background and collection being navigated every time the value is accessed. A pointer is maintained and every time the accessor is being accessed the next value is returned.