# The best practice to design one to many relationship in EF code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Let say, I have two entites such as **Student** and **Department**. There is one to many relationship between them.

**Student.cs**

```
public class Student 
   {
      public int StudentId { get; set; }
      public int StudentName { get; set; }
      public int StudentRoll { get; set; }

      public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
      public Department Department { get; set; }
   }
```

**Department.cs**

```
 public class Department 
   {
      public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
      public int DepartmentName { get; set; }

      public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; } 
   }
```

Instead of using `public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }`, I can use

```
public List<Student> Students { get; set; } 

public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }
```

I saw it in various tutorial in Web. Which one should I use?? I know that it doesn't matter which one I am using but the result is always same. I want to know what is the best practice.

Comment: More important is the `virtual` keyword. Here's a [good answer (for 4.1)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5599270/60761)

Comment: ICollection is default implementations for Navigation Property. The virtual keyword is not necessary needed if you don't need lazy loading.

Comment: Some additional links about Collections/Lists/etc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376708/ilist-vs-ienumerable-for-collections-on-entities, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271710/collectiont-versus-listt-what-should-you-use-on-your-interfaces, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628425/ienumerable-vs-list-what-to-use-how-do-they-work, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398903/what-is-the-difference-between-list-of-t-and-collectionof-t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if its the "best practice", but I do it the way you've done it, but use **virtual** as well.

```
   public class Student 
   {
      public int StudentId { get; set; }
      public int StudentName { get; set; }
      public int StudentRoll { get; set; }

      public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
      public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
   }

   public class Department 
   {
      public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
      public int DepartmentName { get; set; }

      public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; } 
   }
```

I picked up this approach from [Scott Gu blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) . so I hope its good stuff

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is:

```
public virtual IList<Student> Students { get; set; }
```

This allow you to use the methods implemented by IList and enable Entity Framework to create dynamic proxies at runtime.