# IEnumerable vs ToList while directly iterating in view

Tags: c#, entity-framework

If I only have to use that **result** one time i.e. in iterating and displaying in view. I generally do 1st one, is it wiser?

```
IEnumerable<model> result = _someService.GetValues();
return View(result);
```

OR

```
IList<model> result = _someService.GetValues().ToList();
return View(result);
```

I checked in profiler and db is queried only once for that data using EF6.

To clear its a plain SELECT and both has data and there is no adjacent list to kick in lazy loading.

*Note: I know IEnumerable has one method GetEnumerator which executes everytime its called it executes for data whereas ToList() executes only once.*

Comment: It is almost impossible to answer your question without knowing what is happening inside of `GetValues`.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev its a set of same values for both in accordance with model

Comment: and why is this negative, the question seemed clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Programmers.SE: Why should I use `List<T>` over `IEnumerable<T>`?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194083/why-should-i-use-listt-over-ienumerablet):

> There are times when doing a ToList() on your linq queries can be important to ensure your queries execute at the time and in the order that you expect them to.

This is exactly the case here.

If `_someService.GetValues()` returns an `IEnumerable<model>` which is an Entity Framework query through deferred execution, calling `ToList()` in your controller will execute the query there: in your controller, where you can handle the exceptions that may occur. For example a query timeout.

If you don't call `.ToList()`, that same exception will be thrown instead at `@foreach (var item in Model)` in your view. You don't want that.

Also, if you use lazy loading, the context will be disposed by the time the query result end up in your view and throw an exception again, so in that case you'll *have* to materialize the query results in your controller by calling `.ToList()`.

---

People get all high up in a tree when it comes to `IEnumerable<T>` versus `IList<T>`. They are generally parroting each other from some general advice (found [here, amongst others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376708/ilist-vs-ienumerable-for-collections-on-entities)), but they do not understand that that advice is for **API design**. You are not designing an API, you are implementing an application with very specific requirements: the view may never throw an exception. In order to fulfill that requirement, you must execute your queries in your controller, hence call `.ToList()` there.

The user asking the question linked above is right in [the comment they posted](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194083/why-should-i-use-listt-over-ienumerablet#comment374997_194083):

> all queries should be executed so that the model is done and loaded ready for the view. I.e. the view should receive everything and not be querying the database.

Razor rendering your model to your view may not have any side-effects. Executing a query is a side-effect, so that may not happen while rendering your view.

Even when calling `.ToList()` in your controller, your `@model` directive in the view can and should still be of `IEnumerable<T>` though!

Comment: thanks but I was considering more on situation where we do have data, without other adjacent field for lazy loading

Comment: What do you mean by that? You can't tell in advance when an exception will happen, even if you "have data" an exception can occur.

Comment: can you tell me how there would be exception in view that it wouldn't in List and how would in IEnum when iterating? note: I am asking this to you politely

Comment: I think I explained that in my answer, but see the edit which hopefully makes it somewhat more clear. I'm not saying that `.ToList()` _prevents_ an exception, it just makes it appear at that predictable location, and not in your view.

Comment: Even on your provided link "Long story short, use IEnumerable anytime you only need iteration, use IList when you need to index directly and need a dynamically sized array" this more or less answers, but yes exception must be handled which I generally dont :-(

Comment: I added a last line that may give you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: finally got it with the last edit I guess, thanks and did you donwvote?